# How can I pass pipe's filtered data into another function on click event in angular?

Tags: angular, pipe

I have simple one note list in which each note's background color is randomly pick by pipe and set using `style.backgroundColor`

### Html  :

```
<div class="note" *ngFor="let note of noteList" [style.backgroundColor]=" backgroundColors | colorChooser" (click)="openNote(note)">
```

### And My pipe is like this :  (return random color from provided array)

```
transform(arr: Array<string>, ...args: unknown[]): string {
   return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
```

what I want to do that, when Pipe return any value from Array, That is set in background of note div that's fine. But when user click on that note, I want to pass that color into function

## want some thing like this :

```
<div class="note" *ngFor="let note of noteList" (click)="openNote(note, color)"
        [style.backgroundColor]="color = (backgroundColors | colorChooser);">
```

when user click on that note, that note's background color should be display on next page so I want that pipe's returned color in function.

I don't know weather it is possible or not in angular. If anyone knows about it then please answer here.  I really need it. Please help me.

After research about it. I found this : [Angular 2 store piped value in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917699/angular-2-store-piped-value-in-variable)

I can store filtered value into main list of note and then reuse it again. But it's weird and not feasible Solution.

Can I generate variable inside html and then direct pass into another function without use of TS ?

Comment: Can I generate variable inside html and then direct pass into another function without use of TS ? No you can't

Comment: Is there any other method through which I can pass pipe's result into another function ?

Comment: i would suggest to isolate the computation part of the transform function in a .ts file. SO you can use it both for the pipe and for any other reason (inside the 'openNote' function in your use case)

Comment: Thanks For Help Brother. Let me try that one.

Comment: Not sure if it works but you can try. What if you use 'as' after the pipe? Something like this: (backgroundColors | colorChooser) as color

Comment: I would cut out logic from pipe and create some utility function and then import it the pipe and in the component class

Comment: Thanks a Lot Buddy, Yaah that can be possible @Yuriy, But I don't want to use TS.
I found one Solution. Let me post here.

Comment: @ JackyShows, Thanks for Reply Man , `as` is not working. I tried that one.

Answer (score 0):

Yeey, I found Answer After lot's of searching and I made my custom logic for it.

We can pass that result into `ng-template` and then we can use it in multiple places inside `ng-template`

### Here's how I got it worked :

```
<div class="note" *ngFor="let note of noteList">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="noteTemplate;context: {color: backgroundColors | colorChooser}">
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #noteTemplate let-color="color">
            <div class="note-inner" [style.backgroundColor]="color" (click)="openNote(note, color)">
                ...
            </div>
        </ng-template>
</div>
```

I have create one template and then pass filtered value into it and then use it at multiple places.